# SMSS IDE: Addon to colour tab or background by server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I haven't been able to find anything that can colour the background and/or add a tab bar to the SMMS IDE to better identify the difference between prod, test and dev servers. SMSS Tools appears to be the only plugin trying to do this but I'm yet to see it work (appears to be a common problem based on my searches).

Just wondering if anybody knows of an addon (paid or free) that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All version of SSMS since at least SQL Server 2008 R2 (and I think 2008) include a built-in ability to change the colour of the connection bar at the bottom of a query window - when setting up a new connection for a query, click the `Options >>` button, then set the colour by ticking `use custom colour` (then selecting your chosen colour) on the `Connection Properties` tab.

I've had [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) connection colouring working but I prefer the built-in option.

**EDIT**
I just tried SSMS Tools pack colouring again, and I agree it appears not to be working in the current verion (2.1.0) in SSMS 2008 R2.

Comment: Wow, no idea how I missed that / didn't find it with a google search. You're a king amongst men.

Comment: This works in SSMS 2016 as well.  I'd still rather it color my entire query background instead of just the status bar.